# How to turn off compile time errors for Java in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, ide

Is there a way to turn off compile time error display shown in the Java files during programming in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - *Why*?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ I use its screenshots sometimes for presentations where sometimes I show only the relevant part of the code for a concept and I would like the errors not to be displayed at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors

On the right, untick 'Vertical Ruler', 'Overview Ruler' and 'Text as'. Warnings highlighting can also be changed in that menu.